# Get drivers name associated with PID

Tags: c, winapi

I can retrieve modules' name associated with  a specific PID say (1111), and I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve drivers's name belong to the same PID in a similar way?

```
 
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
        PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, procID);
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return 1;


    if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
        {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];

            // Get the full path to the module's file.

            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[i], szModName,
                sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
            {
                // Print the module name and handle value.

                _tprintf(TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i]);
            }
            if(GetModuleBaseName(hProcess,
                hMods[i],
                szModName,
                sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
                _tprintf(TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i]);
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Here, I'm getting all the loaded drivers on the system

```
if (EnumDeviceDrivers(drivers, sizeof(drivers), &cbNeeded) && cbNeeded < sizeof(drivers))
    {
        TCHAR szDriver[ARRAY_SIZE];

        cDrivers = cbNeeded / sizeof(drivers[0]);
        printf("%ls\n", drivers);
        _tprintf(TEXT("There are %d drivers:\n"), cDrivers);
        for (i = 0; i < cDrivers; i++)
        {
            if (GetDeviceDriverBaseName(drivers[i], szDriver, sizeof(szDriver) / sizeof(szDriver[0])))
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("%d: %s\n"), i + 1, szDriver);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't want to get all the drivers on the system. I only need what I'm looking for (by some software).

Comment: Drivers are loaded at OS level (here Windows), not by process.

Comment: If so, How would I then get a a specified software's driver installed on the system?

Comment: Can you add an example of a driver that belongs to a process?

Comment: I don't understand what do u mean by example, but I meant driver associated with certain software. for example, check driver loaded by vmware.exe.

Comment: I added a snippet to illustrate what I need.

Comment: `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemModuleInformation` return list of loaded drivers. drivers not belong to the any PID. and loaded at current time drivers and *driver installed on the system* - different things

Comment: Yeah I got that. However, in this case,how would I retrieve drivers related or belong to the software as I stated before then?

Comment: Drivers do not belong or are related to any given process. They are there, for anyone to use. It's like asking who the value 42 belongs to. It doesn't belong to anyone, it just is. And any process can choose to use or not use it.

Comment: that what I'm trying to say. If "any process choose to use such a driver" how would I retrieve that driver using that process or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

One round-about way to figure out what processes might be using the driver would be to check the function calls they are making.

You would need to find the binaries (and any dependencies) used by a process and check if they make any calls to the driver of interest.

For example, lets pretend a VMWare driver has the function: `vmware_start_vm(...)`

You could search for any binaries or processes that make a call to `vmware_start_vm`